# Visualizing Portfolio Asset Allocation over Time

Tags: time-series, visualization

I've been trying to figure out a good visualization for seeing how the asset allocation within a portfolio changes over time (due to daily returns/losses or cuts to exposure of specific asset). Traditionally, I've seen stacked area charts used to illustrate this, but I find that the viewer is unable to quickly glance at such a chart and understand how the share of the portfolio has changed over time. See my image below to understand what I mean:

[image]

Some changes in asset allocation are easy to see (early 2017 and late 2018), but others are difficult to pinpoint (January 2019, for example).

Does anybody know of any alternative charts which can show such an asset allocation time series visualization more effectively?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps percent increases/decreases on a log scale?